# Ruby on Rails - Order objects by field of a has_many relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm rails begginer.

how to load database that has following condition.

I want show lecture list that has order by comment.created_at DESC

schema.rb

```
  create_table "comments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text     "content"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "lecture_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",             null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",             null: false
    t.integer  "likedcount", default: 0
  end

  create_table "lectures", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "subject"
    t.string   "professor"
    t.string   "major"
    t.datetime "created_at",             null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",             null: false
    t.integer  "uptachi",    default: 0
    t.integer  "hatachi",    default: 0
  end
```

lecture.rb

```
has_many :comments
```

comment.rb

```
belongs_to: lectures
```

Comment: The title of your question is not clear at all, how about "Order objects by field of a has_many relation" (and there sure are even better possibilities, but everything is better than "rails howto").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to write it as:

```
has_many :comments, -> { order("comments.created_at DESC") }
```

As per the OP's comment, it seems, what he want is a named scope. Like,

```
scope :order_by_comments, -> { joins(:comments).order("comments.created_at DESC") }
```

Comment: @lectures=Lecture.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10 )

Comment: <%= will_paginate @lectures %>

Comment: @Jung_digit How the _change_ will come. You didn't call the method which is doing the order by,

Comment: @Jung_digit You call it like `@lectures=Lecture.order_by_comments.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)`